# JPA2 and criteria queries: subqueries with group functions

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I have a native SQL query I would like to express with a JPA2 criteria query.
This query already works, but I haven't been able to get it using just JPA2.
I think mostly because I lack experience on this.
I paste the SQL here, maybe you experts can help me to figure it out:

```sql
SELECT * FROM
   OWNING_POINTS o1
   JOIN
      (SELECT conversationId, count(*) as nOfMsg
       FROM OWNING_POINTS
       GROUP BY conversationId) as o2
       ON o1.conversationId = o2.conversationId
   LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT id, created as newerUnreadMessage
       FROM OWNING_POINTS
       WHERE `read`=0) as o3
       ON o1.id = o3.id " +
WHERE o1.owner_user_id=?
ORDER BY newerUnreadMessage DESC, nOfMsg DESC
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Use QueryDSL instead of Citeria API if You can. Criteria API is a disaster.